# rails strong params unexpected convert string to integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to save model user with phone number, but rails unexpected convert phone from string to integer type

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        log_in @user
        user_response = {
            'user_id' => @user.id
        }
        render json: user_response
    else
        render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

private
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :phone, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

error:

```
Parameters: {"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "phone"=>"12345678901", "username"=>"test", "user"=>{"username"=>"lv", "phone"=>"12345678901"}}

   (0.1ms)  BEGIN

  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`phone` = **BINARY '18610012942'** LIMIT 1

   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK

Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 6ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE:**

migration:

```
class AddPhoneToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :phone, :string, index: true
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :remember_token

validates :phone, presence: true, length: {minimum: 11, maximum: 11},
                      uniqueness: true, format: {with: VALID_PHONE_REGEX}

end
```

Comment: Show your `users` migration `table`

Comment: Show your model code for `users` table please!

Comment: Can you please past here `@user.errors.full_messages`?

Comment: @ArslanAli full_message shows ["Password can't be blank", "Password is too short (minimum is 8 characters)"], but I don't know why

Comment: Instead of `{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "phone"=>"12345678901", "username"=>"test", "user"=>{"username"=>"lv", "phone"=>"12345678901"}}` , it should be like  `{ "user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "phone"=>"12345678901", "username"=>"test"}}`, let's show your `form`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your console output showing

```
{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "phone"=>"12345678901", "username"=>"test", "user"=>{"username"=>"lv", "phone"=>"12345678901"}} ,
```

Instead it should be like this:

```
{"user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "phone"=>"12345678901", "username"=>"test"}}
```

Make changes in `form` according above